# how to request data with the earliest date

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get the earliest date based on all the pins in the database but it only returns data with a date containing a null value. The date field is optional for the user.

I am trying to figure out a way to get the earliest date without returning one with null.

My code is as follows:

```
class MinPinDate(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = pin.objects.all().order_by("Date").reverse()[:1]
    serializer_class = PinSerializer
```

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('api/minPinDate', MinPinDate, 'pin')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
queryset = pin.objects.exclude(Date__isnull=True).order_by("-Date")
```

in which the '-' before "Date" means the descending mode.
So is equivalent to the following:

```
queryset = pin.objects.exclude(Date__isnull=True).order_by("Date").reverse()
```

but using `.order_by("-Date")` should be faster.

Comment: whats the reason with the '-' before date? i got it working without it